# FileSystemWatcher on one server watching folder on another server

Tags: windows-services, filesystemwatcher

I've been reading up on here and other sides about FileSystemWatcher and have still been unsuccessful in finding a solution.

**Issue:** FileSystemWatcher is running on one server(prodserver1) and looking at a folder on another server(prodserver2) and getting the following error :

> "Service cannot be started. System.ArgumentException: The directory name \prodserver2\Public\Synex\R1010\ is invalid.
>      at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher..ctor(String path, String filter)"

This service creates multiple FileSystemWatchers.  R1010 would be replaced with R1011, R2121, etc.  All these directories are stored in the app.config.  Here is what my code looks like:

**App.config:**

```
<!-- <add key ="R1010Directory" value="H:\Synex\R1010\" />
<add key ="R2057Directory" value="H:\Synex\R2057\" />
<add key ="R2190Directory" value="H:\Synex\R2190\" /> -->
<add key ="R1010Directory" value="\\prodserver2\Public\Synex\R1010\" />
<add key ="R2057Directory" value="\\prodserver2\Public\Synex\R2057\" />
<add key ="R2190Directory" value="\\prodserver2\Public\Synex\R2190\" />
```

*Please note I've tried mapping a local drive (H: was mapped to prodserver2\Public).  We tried that route and got the same error.  Going to it in windows explorer, we don't have any issues.

**Service OnStart:**

```
            FileListener R1010Listener = new FileListener();
            R1010Listener.ListenforFile(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["R1010Directory"], "*", "R1010");

            FileListener R2057Listener = new FileListener();
            R2057Listener.ListenforFile(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["R2057Directory"], "*", "R2057");

            FileListener R2190Listener = new FileListener();
            R2190Listener.ListenforFile(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["R2190Directory"], "*", "R2190");
```

**FileListener.cs:**

```
        FileSystemWatcher fileListener = new FileSystemWatcher(inputFileLoc, fileExtension);
        fileListener.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName;
        fileListener.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
        fileListener.InternalBufferSize = 65536;

        // Add event handlers.
        fileListener.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

        // Begin watching.
        fileListener.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

**Additional Information:**

We've changed the Windows Service Logon to my account that I've been pulling up these folders and mapping local drives with.  I went to Services -> Properties -> LogOn tab -> Logon as: this account checked, (when i used my .net account I got access is denied, when I used my prod employee id it accepts it but then I get invalid directory) Browse and select my employee id from our AD -> Apply -> Ok.  This one gets accepted.  When I go to start the service, error above is received.  Something is telling me it still has to be a permissions issue.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research, and some plain luck, I was able to get this to work.

**Using App.Config:**

```
<add key ="R1010Directory" value="\\prodserver2\Public\Synex\R1010\" />
<add key ="R2057Directory" value="\\prodserver2\Public\Synex\R2057\" />
<add key ="R2190Directory" value="\\prodserver2\Public\Synex\R2190\" />
```

**Resolution:**

Here we have 2 types of logins.  "Windows 7 users" and "Novell users".  I'm a windows 7 user, but they have a dummy novell account for me to access other things.  So today was password reset day.  I reset my windows 7 password, went to log into the server I want to have my filesystemwatcher listen for, typed in my password, and got an error "invalid password."  That server was using the novell settings to validate users not our windows settings.  I got our information security team to sync up the two accounts as one, started the service up and it worked.  Another example of a permissions issue.  My service had a valid account, but not a valid account for that server.  Windows Service on prodserv1 is has an activated filesystemwatcher on it listening to directories on prodserver2 and its now working using UNC pathing.  Hope this helps others.